# Capture with Angular the response object sent by the render() method in Symfony 2

Tags: angularjs, symfony

Is it possible to get the response object sent by the `render()` (Symfony2) method?

An example:

```
public function indexAction(){

      $params = array('Hi' =>'Hello world', 'userName' =>'Jack');

      return $this->render('exampleBundle:Default:index.html.twig', $params);
    }
```

I'm totally able to capture the var `$params` and its content in the `html.twig` file, but I can't figure out how to get that content it in javascript to render the view using angular. Just in case, I tried many absurd things, but they didn't work at all obviously.

Maybe it isn't possible at all and I'll need to redesign it or make a new ajax call once the document is loaded instead of passing the content via the `render()` method. I'm not really sure so, can I reach this without make an ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems to me a bad thing. Most of modern client applications philosophy is to to load as soon as possible the web page from server and the load data through xhr request.

Said that if you need or want to do it, you can achieve it in differents manners:

**I did not tried the examples, so this can contains some syntax errors:**

1- JS Vanilla approach; in your `html.twig`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.nameSpaceOfMyApp = window.nameSpaceOfMyApp || {};
    window.nameSpaceOfMyApp.exchange = window.nameSpaceOfMyApp.exchange || {};
    window.nameSpaceOfMyApp.exchange.params = JSON.parse({{$params |json_encode()}});
</script>
```

2- More "Angular Way" Not overloading global namespace and better testing...If you have load angular.js at this point you can create in twig template the main module of your angular App (if you cant use your main module, you can use a new module and require it as dependency of your main module)
in your `html.twig`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('moduleName',[<dependencies>,...])
    .value('exchange',{
        params: JSON.parse({{$params |json_encode()}})
    })
</script>
```

Later you can inject this value where you need it.

```
angular.module('moduleName').controller('nameOfController',['exchange', function(exchange){
    console.log(exchange.params)
}]);
```

Comment: once `app.value(...)` is done, how can I inject it inside a controller?

Comment: I edited my answer, last code block is how you can inject that in a controller, you can see more about values in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers